# As coloring only a specific area within the figure IPAD App Xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios6

How to create an app for color figures like Mikey Mouse and select the color when you click the hat and the hat is the selected color.

The question is how to paint specific areas of the design, such as the arm or hat tie? As coloring only a specific area within the figure.

Link example of Figure:

[image: Figure]
<sub>(source: [xpg.com.br](http://www.not1.xpg.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/imagens-disney-colorir-mickey.gif))</sub>

Comment: I want coloring pages using Touch to Fill